# Opposite of Latin-derived prefix equi-

Tags: word-request, expressions, word-difference, prefixes

My Merriam-Webster dictionary says the prefix stem in words such as the one in "equilateral triangle" (triangle with equal sides), is "equi-", meaning "same".

What I would like to know is, similarly, is there another prefix that can be attached at the beginning of a word to convey the meaning of "different"?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like *contra...* as in *contradiction*? The prefixes *de...*, and *dis...* also carry some similar notions.

Comment: But those stands for "not", or "opposite". Was think bff about something more along the lines of a complement set, if it exists. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example the term is **inequilateral**.
I believe, the prefix to be used depends on the context, there is no universal prefix for 'not equal' that can be applied to all words..